# C# Get Bits from Byte

Tags: c#, byte, bit

I don't know why I am getting wrong bits when reading my byte. I have followed some indications found here, bit it is not working. I show you my code:

```
byte[] byte22And23 = _packet.ReadBytes(2);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.rightEngineSmoke = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 0);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.leftEngineSmoke = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 1);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.rightEngineFire = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 2);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.leftEngineFire = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 3);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.rightRotorFail = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 4);
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.leftRotorFail = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 5);
etc...
```

```
public bool GetBit(byte b, int bitNumber)
    {
        bool bit = (b & (1 << bitNumber - 1)) != 0;
        return bit;
    }
```

My byte 22 has a value of 2, it is: 00000010. And my byte 23 has a value of 0. When I use this code to read byte 22, my 3rd variable (rightEngineFire) is getting "true" (1). It has no sense, it is wrong obviously. But I don't know what is wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: How much do you shift if `bitNumber == 0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetBit()` implementation is wrong, you can check with the following test:

```csharp
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var byte22And23 = new byte[] { 2, 0 };
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 7; i >=0; i--)
    {
        var r = GetBit(byte22And23[0], i);
        sb.Append((r) ? "1" : "0");
    }

    // result: 00000100
    Assert.AreEqual("00000010", sb.ToString());
}
```

It looks like there is no need of `-1` in `GetBit()` because you are indexing bits 0-based and not 1-based:

```csharp
public bool GetBit(byte b, int bitNumber)
{
    // no need of -1 here ------------ˇ
    bool bit = (b & (1 << bitNumber - 1)) != 0;
    return bit;
}
```

After the modification the tests runs green.

Answer (score 5):

You `GetBit` method considers bit numbers to be 1...32, instead of being 0...31.

Simple test:

```
bool b1 = GetBit(1, 0); // false
bool b2 = GetBit(1, 1); // true
```

You should change the method to

```
public static bool GetBit(byte b, int bitNumber)
{
    bool bit = (b & (1 << bitNumber)) != 0;
    return bit;
}
```

Or you could write:

```
DataFromGTAPackets.Packet8.ControlFlags.rightEngineSmoke = _packet.GetBit(byte22And23[0], 1);
```

But in C-derived languages (and C# is a C-derived language) we count from 0, so the first solution is better (for me).

And as a sidenote:

```
1 << bitNumber - 1
```

is quite unreadable, because probably 9 out of 10 programmers don't know/don't remember that the expression means

```
1 << (bitNumber - 1)
```

because in the [operator precedence table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) the `-` comes before the `<<`, so when you mix operators you should use `(...)` to make clear the priority.